# How to add user-defined flags in Google WebRTC?

Tags: c++, webrtc, c++14

This is my first question on Stack Overflow. I am currently working on the implementation of a VOIP application in which I want to send some user-defined and initialized flags from the server-side to the client-side and vice versa.

I have read documentation on [RTP Header Extensions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8285) and [RTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550#page-13). Also, I searched for Sender Reports in [RTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550#page-13) for sending profile-specific information, but couldn't get any help for sending that information in development code. Could anyone please help me and guide me that how can I do that? Can I add user-defined flags in RTP Headers, RTCP Header, or RTP Extension? What will be the process?

I have already tried to implement user-defined information as shown in the following images:

rtp_header_extension.h
[image: rtp_header_extension.h]

rtp_header_extensions.cc
[image: rtp_header_extensions.cc]

rtp_rtcp_defines.h
[image: rtp_rtcp_defines.h]

rtp_header_extension_map.cc
[image: rtp_header_extension_map.cc]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you negotiate with the same uri as an existing extension that is likely to get filtered.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application going to be at both ends of the call? Both peers would need to understand the RTP header extension. Likewise with any custom RTCP flags. It's unlikely this is the approach you want to take.

Alternative options to get your application data from one peer to another are:

- [Data channels](https://webrtc.org/getting-started/data-channels).
- It's a bit hacky but [DTMF events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Using_DTMF) could also be an option for small amounts of information.
- A cutting edge option is [Insertable Streams](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-insertable-streams/). Be aware browser support will be sporadic. The main use case of insertable streams is encryption but in theory there's no reason you couldn't add your metadata in a custom frame format.

Comment: Basically, I am building a WebRTC library which is being used on both ends. So, yes. My application is going to be at both ends. I am trying to send sender information through flags, and not the application data.

Could you please elaborate further on code level in a more programmatic way?

Comment: Ok if you're only intending to create call between your own application then an RTP header extension could be an option. But do you really need to send the flags in every RTP packet? If you're sending audio and video you could easily be transmitting > 100 RTP pkts/second. I don't have any sample code.

Comment: Yes, I want to send it with every packet. Is it possible? Even if you don't have the code could you please explain it to me in the context of WebRTC? Which parameters do I have change in order to add extra information in the headers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it's possible to use an RTP header extension with WebRTC. How you implement it depends on which library you are using. I'm guessing you're using Google's libwebrtc in which case there do seem to be existing extensions. Maybe this can help get you started https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/refs/heads/lkgr/api/rtp_headers.h.

Comment: I have edited the question and added some additional information for the implementations I had made. Please review it and guide me.

Comment: Can anyone please help?

Comment: It doesn't help with your C++ implementation but it seems there maybe a WebRTC extension on the way that helps with RTP extensions, https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#dom-rtcrtpheaderextensioncapability.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to add a simple boolean in default RTP header?

Comment: Could anyone please help? I am still unable to add extra information in sender side and receive it properly on the receiver side.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to metadata.patch in [this commit](https://github.com/phongcao/webrtc-metadata-example/commit/eb19abed4b65f3cb9bd4e9440b5d33c4e8125750). In addition to files you mentioned, you need to modify following files:

- modules/rtp_rtcp/source/rtp_utility.cc (modify `ParseOneByteExtensionHeader` function, add your own type)
- media/engine/webrtc_video_engine.cc (modify `GetCapabilities` function)
- api/rtp_headers.h, api/rtp_parameters.h, api/rtp_parameters.cc (add your own type to `RTPHeaderExtension` and `RtpExtension`)
- modules/rtp_rtcp/source/rtp_sender_video.cc (modify `SendVideo` and `AddRtpHeaderExtensions` function, set your own extension)
- video/rtp_video_stream_receiver.cc (modify `ReceivePacket` function, extract the value of your own extension)

My WebRTC version is M74.